# Windows 8 is frozen when I log on as domain user with local administrator rights

Tags: windows-8

1.Add some domain user to local administrators in Windows 8.

2.log in with this domain user.

3.After several minutes Windows 8 is frozen (I can move mouse pointer but there is no any action to click).

If I exclude this user from administrators and login again everything ok. If I login with local user (not domain) with admin rights everything ok too.

How can fix it?